# method that takes no arguments and returns double

Tags: java

I need to write a public method costMultiplier() that takes no arguments and returns a double. The method should return 1.2 for postcodes beginning “WC1A” or “EC1A”, and 1.0 otherwise.

This is what I have so far but I have added an argument. I am not sure how to answer the question without the argument and how would I test ir accurately. Many thanks

```java
public double costMultiplier(final String postCode) {
    double multiplier = 1.0d; `

    String pc = postCode.trim().toUpperCase(); 

    if (pc.startsWith("WC1A") || pc.startsWith("EC1A")) {
        multiplier = 1.2; 
    }

    return multiplier;
}
```

or I did this but need to include a String???

```
`public static double costMultiplier(){
```

`if(postCode.contains("WC")`

`return 1.2;`
`}`
`else if(postCode.contains("EC")
{
return 1.0;}`

Comment: Unless `postCode` is a global, how are you supposed to return the cost of something - without knowing what the something is? I think this question needs moe *details or clarity*.

Comment: If you must create a function that doesn't take an argument but still needs the postal code to compute something, you will definitely need to specify this postal code somewhere... in a **class** maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can create a `PostCode` class like:

```
public class PostCode {

  private final String code;

  public PostCode(String code) {
    this.code = code.trim().toUpperCase();
  }

  public double costMultiplier() {
    if (code.startsWith("WC1A") || code.startsWith("EC1A")) {
        return 1.2; 
    }
    return 1.0
  }

}
```

then you can do:

```
new PostCode("WC1A").costMultiplier()
```

Comment: its actually part of a project I am doing so there is a class already. I did it another way, please see above this but I need to use a string which this doesnt have.